# How do I view the Xamarin component doc generated by mdoc for Monkey.Robotics on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, mono

How do I view the doc generated by mdoc for Monkey.Robotics on Windows?

Described herein:
https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/API%20Docs

I was able to generate the .zip using mdoc on Windows... but I want to view the doc and not sure how!

I'm running Visual Studio not Xamarin Studio of course.

Comment: Since it calls `mdoc`, you would need to try installing the standalone tooling here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/mdoc/#net-download

Comment: Thanks Jon. I did get past that step. I need to view the mdoc output -- the contents of zip file that it creates. Is there a viewer? Can I load it into VS 2015 somehow?

Comment: I see: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/monodoc/  

Also: The doc browser is part of the mono-tools package, avaliable from the Downloads page.  
  
The I came across this: http://www.mono-project.com/archived/gettingstartedwithmonotools/  

  
This then redirects here: http://mono-tools.com/download/ :(

Comment: I have no clue on that end sorry. I would honestly skip using `mdoc` and `mono` on windows and just generate documentation via a Windows specific tooling and the assembly. The steps on the repo seem to be with MacOS users in mind. But you can always go down the path of installing the mono tools for VS. It just seems a bit excessive to generate docs for an assembly. There's lots of tools that will take the assembly + xml comments and create docs from it.